# why irb plugins not loaded in rails console session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, irb, hirb

I have installed both awsome print & hirb irb plugins to Ruby 1.9.2 through rvm. I can able to access it from irb session. But when i tried from rails console, i got the error

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > require "hirb"
LoadError: no such file to load -- hirb
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: I know there is no need for `rubygems` in rails console, but have you tried `require 'rubygems'` before `require 'hirb'`?

Comment: @rubyprince, nope its not working.. you have to add the necessary gem config in rails gemfile.. check the nash's answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add `hirb` to `Gemfile`.